# Clustering a correlation matrix into multiple matrices of maximum correlations in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, correlation

Say I calculated the correlations of prices of 500 stocks, and stored them in a 500x500 correlation matrix, with 1s on the diagonal.

How can I cluster the correlations into smaller correlation matrices (in Python), such that the correlations of stocks in each matrix is maximized? Meaning to say, I would like to cluster the stocks such that in each cluster, the stock prices are all highly correlated with one another.

There is no upper bound to how many smaller matrices I can cluster into, although preferably, their sizes are similar i.e it is better to have 3 100x100 matrices and 1 200x200 matrix than say a 10x10 matrix, 90x90 matrix and 400x400 matrix. (i.e minimize standard deviation of matrix sizes).

Preferably to be done in Python. I've tried to look up SciPy's clustering libraries but have not yet found a solution (I'm new to SciPy and such statistical programming problems).

Any help that points me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you not just cluster the correlation matrix again?. You could throw it into `seaborn.clustermap` and see how it looks like.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious choice here is hierarchical agglomerative clustering.

Beware that most tools (e.g., sklearn) expect a *distance* matrix. But it can be trivially implemented for a *similarity* matrix instead. Then you can use correlation. This is textbook stuff.